# Invalid literal for float and index out of range issue

Tags: python, flask, arduino

I know this question is already asked but I am unable to figure out this issue. I am using Python Flask for web programming. I am taking my data from the Arduino IDE. So whenever I run the Python program it shows this error saying list out of index. Plus sometimes invalid literal for float. Here is my code:

Python code:

```
import sqlite3
import random
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, jsonify, app, request
from flask import Response
import serial
import time
import json
import math
from time import time,gmtime,strftime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import re

app = Flask(__name__)
obj= serial.Serial( '/dev/ttyS0' ,57600)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')
  @app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
def rand():
  conn = sqlite3.connect('table.db',timeout=15)
  cursor = conn.cursor()
  datestamp = datetime.now()
  values= obj.readline().split(',')
  cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ADC_DATA(Time,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5,data6,data7,data8,data9,data10,data11,data12) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',(datestamp,values[0],values[1],values[2],values[3],values[4],values[5],values[6],values[7],values[8],values[9],values[10],values[11]))
  conn.commit()
  return jsonify(result=float(values[0]),result1=float(values[1]),result2=float(values[2]),result3=float(values[3]),result4=float(values[4]),result5=float(values[5]),result6=float(values[6]),result7=float(values[7]),result8=float(values[8]),result9=float(values[9]),result10=float(values[10]),result11=float(values[11]))
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',threaded=True)
```

For the Arduino, the main part of the code is:

```
void loop() {
  value1 = analogRead(pin1);
  value2 = analogRead(pin2);
  value3 = analogRead(pin3);
  value4 = analogRead(pin4);
  value5 = analogRead(pin5);
  value6 = analogRead(pin6);
  value7 = analogRead(pin7);
  value8 = analogRead(pin8);
  value9 = analogRead(pin9);
  value10 = analogRead(pin10);
  value11 = analogRead(pin11);
  value12 = analogRead(pin12);
  Serial1.print(value1);
  Serial1.print(",");
  Serial1.print(value2);
  Serial1.print(",");
  Serial1.print(value3);
  Serial1.print(",");
  Serial1.print(value4);
  Serial1.print(",");
  Serial1.print(value5);
  Serial1.print(",");
  Serial1.print(value6);
  Serial1.print(",");
  Serial1.print(value7);
  Serial1.print(",");
  Serial1.print(value8);
  Serial1.print(",");
  Serial1.print(value9);
  Serial1.print(",");
  Serial1.print(value10);
  Serial1.print(",");
  Serial1.print(value11);
  Serial1.print(",");
  Serial1.println(value12);
  delay(50);
}
```

Please point out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdKVS.png)

Comment: Please post the full exception traceback.

Comment: Please put the error you receive when you run your code into your question, or else we don't know what causes the error

Comment: Have you checked that `values` is a list of length 12? My guess would be you are getting a different return from `values= obj.readline().split(',')`. Would explain the float literal and bad index exceptions. Try `print(values)`

Comment: @FamousJameous thanks for replying. i updated the question with an error link. please let me know if its visible as i cant upload images right now because i am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Professor_Joykill thanks for replying. i updated the question with an error link.

Answer (score 0):

The message suggests that it is the parsing of serial port via `values= obj.readline().split(',')`. Initially I thought that the problem could be Arduino printing '\r\n' and the line ending you parse with readline is just '\n', but I guess that should work, you'll just be left with '\r' on your `value[11]` (which might cause an SQL issue). However I think the index issue could be due to string encoding.

Try this:
`values = obj.readline().rstrip().decode().split(',')`

FYI it's more convenient for people if you copy+paste your error message from the terminal instead of a picture of it.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I tried this but still facing the same issue

Comment: post the output of `print(values)`

Comment: print(values) gives this :
['246.00', '254.00', '259.00', '262.00', '244.00', '234.00', '233.00', '238.00', '243.00', '247.00', '238.00', '235.00\r\n']                                                                                 Also, the code runs fine sometimes but then suddenly shows these list index and invalid literal for float error.

Comment: Ok is this the output from one of the times when the code does run correctly? You could add some simple checks like `print(len(values)) ` and see if `values` isn't length 12 when you get the error. (A good practice would be to use `try` / `except` block to catch an IndexError.)

Comment: Also, the `\r\n` in the last value might be the cause of the occasional float conversion error. Use `.rstrip().split(",")`.

Comment: thanks for your time. index error is gone now. but as i stated before. python still throws invalid literal for float error sometimes. why?

Comment: Can you post the full error message? If it's traceback is at the same line, you are just going to have to see what the contents of `values` looks like when you get the error. Could be that one of the entries is empty or contains 'NaN' or something if the Arduino could not read that pin.